# Cut a variable to it's fields one by one

Tags: linux, bash

I have a variable like this(Tab seperated):

"a  b  c  d"

I want to read fields one by one, but the problem is number of fields are not fixed, I mean the variable may contain no field or 3 fields or 100 fields or more.

I don't know the best way I can handle it.
Can any one show me a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've found so far:

```
$ x=$'a a\t*\t c\td\te'
```

`$x` is my test variable containing tab separated fields.

```
$ IFS=$'\t'
```

Words are separated by tabs only, not spaces or newlines.

```
$ set -f
```

Disable globbing.

```
$ for i in $x; do echo "$i"; done
a a
*
 c
d
e
```

Loop over the words in `$x` with each element in `$i`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `read` command.

```
IFS=$'\t' read -a fields <<< $'a b\tc d\te f'
for f in "${fields[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

The output is

```
a b
c d
e f
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut -f#` like so:

```
$ cat string
a       b       c       d
$ cut -f1 string
a
$ cut -f2 string
b
$ cut -f3 string
c
$ cut -f4 string
d
```

... or in a shell script ...

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

var="a  b       c       d"
echo $var | cut -d' ' -f1
echo $var | cut -d' ' -f2
echo $var | cut -d' ' -f3
echo $var | cut -d' ' -f4
$ ./test.sh
a
b
c
d
```

... or maybe ...

```
$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/sh

var="a  b       c       d"
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\t")
for v in $var
do
    echo $v
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
$ ./test2.sh
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the variable Z containing "a b c d".  You can create an array variable where split from Z as follows:

```
ZA=( $Z )
```

Then the individual elements are accessible as `${ZA[0]}`, `${ZA[1]}` etc..

You can then perform some operation on each part of the variable:

```
for part in ${ZB[@]}; do
    echo $part  # or whatever you want to do with it
done
```

This is a slightly more structured approach, as you can actually utilise word splitting more directly in the `for` statement:

```
for part in $Z; do
    echo $part  # or whatever you want to do with it
done
```

The word splitting is done whereever characters in the shell variable IFS are encountered.  You can change the characters if you want.

Note that this kind of splitting approach is done inside the shell, so it's much faster than spawning `awk` or an external `cut` program, but it's also less portable across shells.

Comment: If the field contain space, this approach will split the value into too many fields.

Comment: @chepner: true that - the comment above about IFS addresses it though: you can use `IFS=' '`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $variable|awk '{print $1}' #will print the first field
echo $variable|awk '{print $2}' #will print the second field
echo $variable|awk '{print $NF}' #will print the last field
echo $variable|awk '{print NF}' #will print the number of fields
```

tested below:

```
> setenv var "a b c d"
> echo $var|awk '{print $1}'
a
> echo $var | awk '{print $2}'
b
> echo $var | awk '{print $NF}'
d
> echo $var | awk '{print NF}'
4
>
```

Comment: That fails if `variable_which_has_the_tab_separated_fields` contains spaces, `*`, `?`, ...

Comment: This does not work! It will print the whole variable at once.

Comment: The failing part (as you said) was right, the problem was that I put my variable in "" so it does not work, when I used it without "" it worked fine.